# Code to find frequency in a list. The 2nd code the one with the count function works just fine, but 1st method using loops doesn't work, why?

Tags: python, list, set, counting, ranged-loops

```
check = set()
for i in range(len(names)):
    count = 0
    for j in range( len(names)):
        if names[i] == names[j]:
            count +=1
        my_tup = (names[j], count)
        check.add(my_tup)
print(check)
```

> this code doesn"t give the correct output which is as follows:
> **{('m', 2), ('m', 1), ('b', 1), ('p', 3), ('b', 0), ('p', 2), ('b', 3), ('m', 0), ('m', 3), ('b', 2), ('p', 1)}**

```
names = ["b", "b", "b", "m", "p", "p", "m"]
    #made the set so that I can record the frequencies of each word only once,
     #since it doesn't allow repetation
    check = set() 
    for i in names:
    #tuple, because it's hashable
        my_tup = (i, names.count(i))
        check.add(my_tup)
    
    print(check)
```

> This code gives the correct output, which is as follows:
> **{('m', 2), ('p', 2), ('b', 3)}**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter` for this job.

```
from collections import Counter 
print(Counter(["b", "b", "b", "m", "p", "p", "m"]))
```